# Prevent iPhone from dialing 911

Tags: iphone

I have a family member who has dementia. Their iPhone was taken away because they kept dialing 911. I gave the family member an iPod Touch, but they really want an iPhone. I took the SIM card out of the iPhone, but discovered that it is still possible to call 911.

Is there a way to disable the 911 dialing functionality of the iPhone in the United States?

Comment: Why do they want and iPhone with no SIM - what does an iPod Touch (or iPad) not do?

Comment: The family member has Frontal Lobe Dementia, which impacts reasoning abilities. The person doesn't want the iPod because they want an iPhone. There is no logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot disable it for an US iPhone as US law requires that all cell phones be able to call 911 even if no SIM-card is inserted.

You would need to obtain a foreign iPhone. For example in the EU the emergency services are typically not dialed with 911 but rather 112.